# What is wrong with this assembly code intended to emulate a loop?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, nasm

This code is supposed to say *Hello World* five times!

```
org 100h

string db 'Hello World',0Dh,0Ah,'$'
mov dx,string
mov bl,0

check:
cmp bl,5
jb print
ja term

print:
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov ah,04Ch
int 21h
inc bl
jmp check

term:
ret
```

I'm getting only one Hello World as the output!
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You're explicitly exiting the program (by INT 21h with AH=4Ch) after printing your string once!

It also looks like you're trying to execute the "Hello World" string as if it was code (sinc you're putting it at address 100h where the OS will start executing the program). Why that does not crash your program before it gets to print *anything* must be a case of pure luck.

Comment: Wow! To be honest I'm quite a noob trying to learn ALP from scratch! Thanks a lot for the info man! Yes, indeed the program kept crashing and a dialog box would with some 16 Bit error!
After I put the define byte instruction at the end, only then the output would come as one single Hello World!

Comment: Awesome! It worked! Thanks man! :)

BTW, could you please explain what is the purpose of the origin instruction in the beginning of the code?
And when to use the 4Ch value in the Ah register?

Comment: org 100h is legacy from DOS era, when .com files were restricted to 64K bytes. The "operating system" used the first 256 of the Code Segment to pass e.g. command line arguments; loaded the next 65280 bytes from the .com file and jumped to the address 0x100 in the code segment CS. org in assembler sets then the 'origin' of each instruction relative to the assumed load address.